# How to communicate android application with Bluetooth-enabled device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

What is the required to allow android application to communicate with Bluetooth-enabled devices (that uses the `easy Bluetooth module`)?

Do I need to use the normal `BluetoothAdapter` class . I have tried the chat example attached with android samples. But the android application can't discover the Bluetooth device ?
What is the problem , do I need to use Bluetooth profiles ?

Comment: I haven't connected to a health device yet but have you read through the **[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHealth.html)** yet regarding connections to health devices?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Answer (score 2):

Typically these modules using Serial profile, so you can use BluetoothAdapter normally. I've a similar module that is attached to a micro-controller and it is working fine with Android app.

- Make sure that the module is running in the "Slave" mode *if it is configurable*.
- Search for the module from Bluetooth settings and **pair** with it before running your application.

Here is a quick code snippet to connect to a known device over Serial profile

```
String BTAddress = "ADD YOUR REMOTE DEVICE BLUETOOTH ADDRESS HERE"; // has the format 00:00:00:00:00:00
UUID SERIAL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
BluetoothDevice btDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BTAddress);
btSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SERIAL_UUID);
btSocket.connect();
```